# Writing an IF statement in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

- I have inserted a check box (form control) with the title "wall".
- Next to this I have the cell stating "False" if unticked and "True" if ticked.
- Next to this are two cells with the dimensions of the wall "length", "height". - Lastly is the cell containing "area of the wall".

I want to write an IF statement in the "area of the wall" cell so that when the check box IS ticked, the area of the wall is printed, and if it is NOT ticked it prints N/A If have written:

```
 =IF((C2="TRUE"), (D2*E2), ("N/A"))
```

All that happens is the cell reads N/A, no matter whether the box is ticked or not. Any help please on how to correct this? [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N45Qw.jpg)

Comment: Try changing to `=IF(C2, D2*E2, "N/A") ` and see what happens.

Comment: `=IF(C2=TRUE` ... will work as well, if you want the full words written out. The reason the `"TRUE"` does not work is that the `"`s tell Excel to evaluate `TRUE` as a text string and not a Boolean expression.

Answer (score 1):

True should not be in quotes, it's treating it like a string when it's a boolean. Removing the quotes should work or writing TRUE()

The final formula should look like this:

```
=IF((C2=TRUE), (D2*E2), ("N/A"))
```

Comment: I did not, just saw no answers, I apologize.